# Only then or then only?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

I am not a native speaker. I have seen people at my place uses similar kinds of sentences interchangeably.

> If he comes, **only then** I will go.
>
> If he comes, **then only** I will go.

Which of these sentences is correct or appropriate if the desired meaning is that *his coming is the required condition,* not that *a single person (me) will go*?

Comment: As so often happens with a "which is correct" question, those sentences are both syntactically correct, but they have different meanings.

Comment: it depends on what you are saying -- is the "only" modifying the condition that needs to be satisfied before you can go or the number of people who who will go?

Comment: @Dan: modifying the condition, Not the number of people.

Comment: It's not possible to tell which is appropriate because there is not enough context and no indication of what the desired meaning is. Please **edit the question** to add this.

Comment: @Inquisitive if you mean modifying the condition then you need "only then will I go."

Comment: @Dan: What is the difference between, "only then will I go" and "only then I will go" ?

Comment: A native speaker would say, "I'll only go if he comes [too]."

Comment: @Inquisitive: the accepted ordering of sentences in English can admittedly be quite confusing. We'd never say _If he comes, only then I will go_. We might say _If he comes, only then will I go_ - but it sounds a little starchy. We'd often say _If he comes, then I will go_.  I'd prefer something like _John may be attending the lecture; only then will I go._ Jim's alternative is more natural-sounding, as is "I'm not going unless _he_ is."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"... then only I will go" is the structure that comes following the sentence structure of most Indian languages.

Such a structure is a kind of pseudo-regionalism which is commonly followed and correctly understood by the locals. However, it is **incorrect** to use the word order " *then only*" to convey the meaning you intend here -- "*only then*" is the correct phrase.

Answer (score 3):

> If he comes, only then I will go.

If he comes I will go. If he does not come, I will not go. This might be better phrased "Only if he comes, will I go" for clarity.

> If he comes, then only I will go.

If he comes, then I will be the only one to go.

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference between the two statements.